# PHP Dynamic preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

`$end = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);`

How can I make the replacement string $replacement vary with each match in $str? For example, I want to replace each matched string with an associated image. Something about callbacks... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, something with callbacks. Specifically [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), which makes repeated calls redundant. For a list of things to replace:

```
 $src = preg_replace_callback('/(thing1|thing2|thing3)/', 'cb_vars', $src);
```

Where the callback can do some form of lookup or conversion:

```
 function cb_vars($m) {
     return strtoupper($m[1]);
 }
```

Likewise can you do that inline with the normal [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) and the `/e` modifier.

Comment: Yes! Awesome, I was having trouble reading the php docs. Thanks for spelling it out...

Answer (score 3):

You need to either use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), or the `/e` modifier in the pattern string. The first is more powerful, but the second is more convenient if you are only after something relatively simple.